# JQuery .append() Only Appends Capital Characters

Tags: javascript, jquery, cordova, unicode, append

I'm working on a Cordova quote generator app where the user can add their own custom quotes.

I have a list of default quotes that are stored as a JavaScript object for reference. I was testing a for loop to display all of my quotes in a list where the idea is to display them as buttons so the user can click on the quote and edit the text.

My problem is when using `.append()` to add `<li>` elements to the `<ul>`, the displayed HTML shows only uppercase characters and punctuation marks.

There are a few other weird characters that make it seem like the problem is a Unicode issue but I'm not sure. I was trying to test it where the button shows the author of the quote. I referenced the name using `quoteSource[i].name`.

Edit: I did check that my CSS has the font I wanted is declared as `!important` and I do not have a typeface that looks like the one displayed. I did try to add the code manually and it worked like it's supposed to.

Some code from my JS object:

```
var quoteSource=[
    {
        id: 1,
        quote: "Start by doing what's necessary; then do what's possible; and suddenly you are doing the impossible.",
        name:"Francis of Assisi"
    },
    {
        id: 2,
        quote:"Believe you can and you're halfway there.",
        name:"Theodore Roosevelt"
    },
    {
        id: 3,
        quote:"It does not matter how slowly you go as long as you do not stop.",
        name:"Confucius"
    },
    {
        id: 4,
        quote:"Our greatest weakness lies in giving up. The most certain way to succeed is always to try just one more time.",
        name:"Thomas A. Edison"
    },
    {
        id: 5,
        quote:"The will to win, the desire to succeed, the urge to reach your full potential... these are the keys that will unlock the door to personal excellence.",
        name:"Confucius"
    },
    {
        id: 6,
        quote:"Don't watch the clock; do what it does. Keep going.",
        name:"Sam Levenson"
    },
    {
        id: 7,
        quote:"A creative man is motivated by the desire to achieve, not by the desire to beat others.",
        name:"Ayn Rand"
    },
    {
        id: 8,
        quote:"Start where you are. Use what you have. Do what you can.",
        name:"Arthur Ashe"
    },
    {
        id: 9,
        quote:"Ever tried. Ever failed. No matter. Try Again. Fail again. Fail better.",
        name:"Samuel Beckett"
    },
    {
        id: 10,
        quote:"Be yourself; everyone else is already taken.",
        name:"Oscar Wilde"
    }];
```

My function to display the list:

```
function customQuotes() {
    quoteTitle.innerHTML = "Custom Quotes";
    quoteActivity.style.display = "block";
    addButton.style.display = "block";
    quoteList.html('');
    for(i=0;i<sourceLength;i++) {
        quoteList.append('<li class="item-list-li"><i class="material-icons list-item-icon>edit</i><p class="list-item-text">' + quoteSource[i].name + '</p></li>'); 
    }

}
```

I do have another function that works similarly to the one above that displays the whole quote object to the screen that seems to work fine. Heres a snippet of that code:

```
function setQuote(a) {
    newQuoteText = quoteSource[a].quote;
    newQuoteGenius = quoteSource[a].name;
    newQuoteId = quoteSource[a].id;
    if ((newQuoteGenius === null) || (newQuoteGenius == "") || (newQuoteGenius == " ")) { newQuoteGenius = "Unknown" }
    quoteContainer.fadeOut(timeAnimationIn, function () {
        quoteContainer.html('');
        quoteContainer.append('<p class="quote">' + newQuoteText + '</p>' + '<p id="name" class="name">' + '-' + newQuoteGenius + '</p>');
        quoteContainer.fadeIn(timeAnimationOut);
    });
}
```

I also noticed that when trying to print the 'edit' character from Material Icons, the character does not show up in the document. Also, the typeface is incorrect and should look like the typeface in the title (reference attached images).

Here are some screenshots, I circled the two of the characters that made me suspect a Unicode problem:

[image: Screenshot 1]

[image: Screenshot 2]

Here is a jsfiddle of my problem. To see what it's supposed to look like just coment out the `customQuotes()` call at the bottom of the JS. 
https://jsfiddle.net/dbzte38m/

Comment: Please provide us with a working example of the problem, honest i think it migth be a style problem

Comment: Looks like that font only has uppercase characters.  The symbols might be where you have a `;`

Comment: @freedomn-m I did consider that as a possibility. When I copy and paste the same code that is in `.append()` to the HTML document, it works like it's supposed to. I made sure I defined the font I wanted as !important. Also, I checked the names and not all names that show one of those symbols don't have a semi-colon anywhere in the name.

Comment: @CarstenLøvboAndersen I created a JSFiddle that shows the problem. I edited my post.

Comment: It's definitely the font.  You're missing the close quote in `<i class="material-icons list-item-icon>` so it's creating mal-formed html and applying `material-icons` to the following `<p>`.  Updated fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/0ctzn47v/   Hope that helps you move on.  Voted this question to close as typo.